# ir.rule with a related field, only working with new records [Odoo v8]

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I have this `ir.rule`. I want a group only see their own records on `account.voucher`.

```
<record id="ir_rule_account_voucher_restrictions" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">Voucher Restrictions</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref='model_account_voucher'/>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('group_users_restrictions'))]"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[('user_id', '=', user.id)]</field>
</record>
```

`account.voucher` didn't have a `user_id` field, so I have to create it now. The only way I have to recover the older `user_id` is with `message_follower_ids` field, so I have this new field

```
class AccountVoucher(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.voucher'

    user_id = fields.Char(string='Salesperson', related="message_follower_ids.name", store=True)
```

And it's working OK with the new records I'm creating, but I also need the old records to make the ir.rule work

[image: The first record is the one I've created]

I think the problem is the same with computed fields, they don't get stored on db.
How should I add to accomplish my task?

Comment: Why not using the followers in the domain like in portal rules, for example for [sales orders](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9e8f70e4849b0eeaca8b5cf51372ecfa23dc561b/addons/portal_sale/security/portal_security.xml)?

Answer (score 0):

`message_follower_ids` is a `Many2many` field.
Relating `user_id` as `Char` field might be inconsistent.

I'm not sure comparing `name` with `user.id` would work. Consider storing `id` field instead.

Also you are storing `.name` field so this would return an error in case there should be multiple followers.

To recompute fields in Odoo v8 you can use server actions:

```
model = env['account.voucher']
object = model.search([])
env.add_todo(model._fields['user_id'], object)
model.recompute()
```

You can anyway avoid creating a related field because `message_follower_ids` is already present in your model (since you are inheriting `mail_thread`)

So your domain can be semplified:

`<field name="domain_force">[('message_follower_ids', 'in', [user.id])]</field>`

Note i'm using `in` operator since `message_follower_ids` is parsed as a list of `ids`, so correct operation is to check if `message_follower_ids` contains your current logged in `user.id`

In my advice, best practice would be to have a real relation (not based on `message_follower_ids`) in `account.voucher` model.

```
class AccountVoucher(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.voucher'

    user_id = fields.Many2one(
      string='Salesperson',
      comodel_name="res.users",
      default=lambda self: self.env.user.id
    )
```

Then migrate (manually or via script) previous records.

```
for acc_id in self.env['account.voucher'].search([('user_id', '=', False]):
  acc_id.write({'user_id': acc_id.message_follower_ids[0].id})
```

If you're going to use odoo shell, don't forget to:

```
self.env.cr.commit()
```